# My robot framework test does not work with chrome

Tags: google-chrome, robotframework

I have written some test suites with robot framework using RIDE. As browser I have used Firefox and all test passed without any problem. But I have now to use Chrome as reference browser. But chrome isn't working. So I have done a very simple test case:

```
Open Browser    http://google.com    ${BROWSER}
```

If I enter "ff" as my *${BROWSER}* variable I get a Firefox window with the google website displayed within it.
 
When I change the *${BROWSER}* variable to chrome, I get a browser window which is black.
I get the following error in the log file:

```
    WebDriverException: Message: session not created exception
from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
  (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

My configuration is:

```
Robot Framework 3.0
RIDE 1.5.2.1
Selenium2Library 1.7.4
Python 2.7.12
wx 2.8.12.1
Google Chrome 55
Chromedriver 2.27
```

Comment: Its a driver problem try with other driver version

Comment: I have tried all chromedriver versions from 2.0 up to 2.27 and it is still not working.